# Entity Framework Update Records Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hi i am running into some issues when trying to do an update on a nested collection using Entity Framework. I am using Entity Framework Core but I don't know if that make a difference with this issue.

The application should allow people to be tagged and untagged in a photo.

I am using WebApi and trying to send a patch to update some details but the update doesn't seem to work.

Here is the data model:

Here is my Photo class

```
public class Photo
{
    private Photo() { }

    public Photo(string title, string location)
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Title = title;
        Location = location;
        Persons = new HashSet<PersonPhoto>();

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Location { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<PersonPhoto> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Photos = new HashSet<PersonPhoto>();
    }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my PersonPhoto class

```
public class PersonPhoto
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
}
```

I am sending a JsonPatch document containing a PhotoViewModel to the endpoint and I would expect the result to either update or remove a record for the PhotoPerson joining table.

Here is the PhotoViewModel

```
public class PhotoViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public List<int> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the endpoint that I am posting to:

```
public IActionResult TagPhoto(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<PhotoViewModel> patch)
{
    // Get Photo first
    var photos = _uow.Photos.GetPhoto(id);

    var photoVM = Mapper.Map<Photo, PhotoViewModel>(photos);

    patch.ApplyTo(photoVM);

    var photo = Mapper.Map<PhotoViewModel, Photo>(photoVM);

    foreach (var i in photoVM.Persons)
    {
        photo.Persons.Add(new PersonPhoto()
        {
            PersonId = i
        });
    }

    _uow.Photos.UpdatePhoto(photo);
    _uow.Complete();

    return Ok();
}
```

The mapper that maps a PhotoViewModel to a Photo Entity looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PhotoViewModel, Photo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Persons,
                        opts => opts.Ignore());
```

The mapper that maps a Photo Entity to a PhotoViewModel looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Photo, PhotoViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Persons,
                map => map.MapFrom(p => p.Persons.Select(c => c.PersonId)));
```

and the Repository that handles the data access has this update method:

```
  public void UpdatePhoto(Photo photo)
    {
        contextTest.Entry(photo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Whats currently happening:

If I update the PhotoViewModel properties other than the collection of Persons then the database is updated accordingly. Sql Profiler shows that the update statement contains the new property change (title for example) however when I try to update the nested collection nothing happens in the database and sql profiler has no mention of the nested collection. It just seems to ignore it.

I've tried a few different things. I changed the repository to update like this:

_context.Photos.Update(photo)
This just kept adding new records into the joining table (duplicates too) when I would try to remove from the nested collection nothing would every be removed from the joining table.

Am I missing something really obvious? I've been looking around online but I can't really see a solution for this.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

** Edit **

The _context.SaveChanges() ocurrs in my UnitOfWork here:

```
 public void Complete()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I see no `_context.SaveChanges()` call in any place which should be the last step (That actually submit the changes to the database)

Comment: I make that call in the _uow.Complete() function. I'll update the question to reflect that

Comment: Try adding also the PhotoId when you fill the list of PersonPhoto:     `foreach (var i in photoVM.Persons)
    {
        photo.Persons.Add(new PersonPhoto()
        {
            PersonId = i, PhotoId = photo.Id
        });
    }`